# PM2 or any npm module Stuck at the start of installation

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install PM2 for node.js, But whenever i am installing it gets stuck at the very start,I tried googling it but cant find anything related to my problem,I am on Windows 10,I cannot install any module!

Comment: show some log about this issue

Comment: at which point do you get stuck? Running `npm install -g pm2`?

Comment: Yes,i get stuck around npm install -g pm2 It's progress bar is only a bit over the start and its been standing there for a day already,I tried doing npm install pm2 without the -g same. http://prntscr.com/doy8zs

Comment: We ran into this issue on one of our servers and it was due to npm being out of date. Check that out

Comment: Yeah,I just saw that,I tried downloading node.js and reinstalling it but still doesnt work,How do i update npm?

Comment: I updated node.js but i still cannot install 'ANY' modules

Comment: I updated node.js and npm still cannot install ANY modules or packages

Comment: Someone answer please?

Comment: Solved,I reinstalled my windows ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled my windows and thats it,No one was able to help except telling me to update npm which i did but didnt work.